# Replacing function call with procedure execution in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I had a function called `dbo.Match`.It was an `inline TVF` that I replaced with a procedure called `dbo.Match` that has a select statement at its end to select rows from a table so that I can direct the results of select query when I execute `dbo.Match` to a temporary table called `#Temp`.

Now if it was a function, I was using this query :

```
if @MotherFN is not null 
  begin

    SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight 
    FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights 
    WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 20;
    INSERT INTO #Temp2                   
(RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
  SELECT RowId, 
         @MotherFN  ,
        'mothersfirstname'
        ,PercentMatch,
         @constVal,
         PercentMatch * @constVal
  FROM   dbo.Match(@MotherFN)

    end
```

Now, I need to execute `dbo.Match` procedure instead of `dbo.Match` function.How I may make this execution call and insert data in `#Temp` table like I was doing with function call ?

***Problem :***  Calculating `PercentMatch * @constVal` and inserting in `#Temp` in same step efficiently. Procedure dbo.Match would return `rowId` and `PercentMatch` only. I need to insert values of RowId and PercentMatch in `#Temp` along with value of  `@constVal` and a value for result of multiplication of `PercentMatch` and `@constval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the procedure accept these following parameters

```
@MotherFN , @constVal
```

And do the following inside the procedure , in select statement that returns the procedure's result set.

```
  SELECT RowId, 
         @MotherFN  ,               --<-- In proc definition 
        'mothersfirstname'
        ,PercentMatch,
         @constVal,                 --<-- In proc definition 
         PercentMatch * @constVal   --<-- In proc definition
```

And for insert simply do

```
INSERT INTO #TemP (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName
                       ,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
Exec dbo.Match(@MotherFN , @constVal)
```

Comment: I thought of it too but I consider it would be passing too many arguments unnecessarily just to get these back where they were passed from. Has to be something better than that for the problem

Comment: Two arguments are not two many arguments :) , Also passing these parameters to a stored procedure and getting them back, will be better than doing them outside of the procedure, as whatever is done inside a procedure will be (execution plan) cached and will have better performance as compare to if you were to do it out side of a proc.

Comment: @M. Ali : Oh, is that ? Thank you :)I had no idea it may have better performance for that reason. Thanks a ton for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You options are more limited with a procedure.

You can use `insert into ... exec ...` to insert the results of the procedure into a temporary table, but you can't really combine it with another query. (Well you could use `openrowset` with dynamic SQL, but that will get nasty very quickly).

For example something like:

```
if @MotherFN is not null 
begin
    select
        @constVal = FunctionWeight 
    from
        dbo.FunctionWeights 
    where
        FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 20;

    insert into #Temp2 (
        RowId, ColumnName, ValFromFunc
    ) exec
        dbo.Match(@MotherFN);

    update
        #Temp2
    set
        ValFromUser = @MotherFN,
        FuncWeight = @constVal,
        percentage = PercentMatch * @constVal;
end;
```